# Angularjs validation time showing invalid

Tags: angularjs

I have the next angularjs input time tag in my markup.

I am trying to do validation in form.

When I have the next values in my view, my form is invalid:

```
frmAg.input.$error = {"max":true}

Model value to AG_HOR_ATEND_INICIAL="2017-11-03T10:00:00.000Z"

View value to AG_HOR_ATEND_INICIAL="08:00"
```

I´d like to know why my input has invalid "max" if my time input is into the max and min range time.

//markup

```
 <form name="frmAg" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
   <input name="input" id="horarioInicioAtendimento" type="time" 
                  min="05:00:00" max="23:59:00"
                  ng-model="AG_HOR_ATEND_INICIAL" placeholder="HH:mm" class="form-control" required> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//this how you assign the value
$scope.AG_HOR_ATEND_INICIAL = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 08, 00, 0);
```

Read this link for more information : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

Comment: @LuizAlves pleasure